# 2 limits logarithms $ \lim_{t\to \infty} t-t^2\ln(\frac{t+1}{t}) $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have problems with the following limits logarithms, and I can not use L'Hopital or power series (I know the results of the problems, using these methods), so I need solutions that do not occupy these resources

$$\displaystyle  \lim_{t\to \infty} t-t^2\ln\left(\frac{t+1}{t}\right) $$

$$\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0^+}\dfrac{t\ln(t^2)}{\ln t +1} $$

any help is appreciated 
regards :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $$ \lim_{t\to \infty} t-t^2\ln\left(\frac{t+1}{t}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\left({x+1}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\ln(x+1)}{x^2}$$
  Now since you don't want use neither L'Hôpital nor the Taylor series so define the function $f(x)=\ln(x+1)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}$ and prove that $0\leq f(x)\leq \frac{x^3}{3}$ and conclude.
- Since 
  $$1=_0o\left(\ln t\right)$$
  so
  $$ \lim_{t \to 0^+}\dfrac{t\ln(t^2)}{\ln t +1}= \lim_{t \to 0^+}\dfrac{2t\ln(t)}{\ln t }= \lim_{t \to 0^+}2t=0$$

Comment: is the power series of $ln(1+x)$, i need a answer that dont have power series, thx anyway

Comment: @kEoz I edit my answer hoping helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For the second one, note:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{t\ln(t^{2})}{\ln t + 1} = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{2t\ln(t)}{\ln t + 1} = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{2t}{1 + \frac{1}{\ln t}} = 0$$

Comment: thx, i dont know how dont see these ;)

Comment: @kEoz, my pleasure! The more you see and practice with the more you will recognize. :)

Comment: I may be being silly here.. but what exactly is $ln 0$ from the rightside? If it's $- \infty$ as I am thinking, how exactly are you determining that this limit is equal to zero? Even if you use L'Hopital's rule you get $$\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{2}{-\frac{1}{t ln^2 t}}$$

Comment: @DanZimm, exactly. Hence, as we approach zero from the right side, $\frac{1}{\ln t}$ approaches $\frac{1}{-\infty} = 0$. Is this clear?

Comment: @AWertheim I understand what you're saying but that isn't really true, you can't really treat $\infty$ as a number - I may be being too nitpicky for this question but you really can't say $\frac{1}{-\infty} = 0$ (I suppose unless of course this situation permits it, which, again, I'm not sure if it does)

Comment: @DanZimm, why not? It's quite possible that I'm wrong, but I don't believe that I'm treating infinity as a number. I'm almost certain that it's true that $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{1}{\ln t} = 0$. In fact, it should be true that $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{1}{f(t)} = 0$ for ANY $f(t) \rightarrow \pm \infty$ as $t \rightarrow 0^{+}$. Could you please try to explain the issue you have with this?

Comment: @AWertheim yes I agree with both of those other statements, but IMO you require a bit more explanation in your answer then, i.e. what you put here in the comments. Also note that you are not saying now that $\frac{1}{-\infty} = 0$ but you are talking about limits - theyre pretty different IMO